# unseen syntax: struct::template X

Tags: c++, templates, using, typename

I stumbled over a piece of code that I do not understand.
In one file:

```
namespace traits {
  template <typename... Base>
  struct use_ : Base... {
  };

/* some more stuff here */

  using useDefaults = use_<>;
}
```

and in another file:

```
template<typename T>
using InputHandle_t = typename Traits::useDefaults::template InputHandle<T>;
```

What I do not understand the `useDefaults::template something` syntax.
What does this do?

PS: If I did not give enough context to understand my problem, please let me know!

Comment: It's a reverse dupe, hope it's okay

Comment: looks good, thank you! didn't find that myself^^

Comment: In fact it's superfluous, no dependent names here. `Traits::useDefaults::InputHandle<T>` should be fine. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EWrKpEtShVvMXcnk).

Comment: i simplified the code, it is `template<typename Tr, typename T> using inputhandle_t = typename Tr::template InputHandle<T>;`

Comment: also, how did you do get the live link from wandbox?